# Función REPLACE en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM TERRITORIO
```

Y este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede observar que los nombres están repetidos solo que los primeros tres tienen un espacio antes del nombre, me podrían decir como quitar solo el primer espacio ya que intente esto:

```
SELECT REPLACE(NOMBRE,' ','') FROM TERRITORIO
```

pero en el territorio Mexico Sur tambien se remplaza el espacio y queda MexicoSur

Comment: Puedes usar la función `TRIM()` en lugar de `REPLACE()`.

Comment: Sería una buena opción que se pueda limpiar los valores mediante un `UPDATE` para evitar tener que quitar los espacios cada vez que se consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En mi comentario añadí que podias usar la función `TRIM()`, pero creo que solo esta disponible apartir de SQL 2017, una alternativa a versiones anteriores puede ser:

```
SELECT LTRIM(nombre) FROM territorio
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero creo que faltaría explicarle al OP qué es lo que hace la función `trim` o por qué es más apropiada que `replace`.